# Fake Pan Gesture in Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer, pan

I'm trying to fake pan gesture, but am not sure how to do it. There is some complicated code determining what happens with the pan gesture, so before going in and abstracting out all the logic, I was wondering if anybody knew of a way to fake the gesture. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "fake pan gesture"? Do you mean to move the view to the left in code without the user dragging their finger?

Comment: Why do not use simple animation to move view?

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than moving the view. I apologize about writing that bit in there.

Comment: Then try to add details what effect you want to achieve and what you have done yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the API does not provide a way to trigger the gesture programmatically nor does it provide public access to the targets and selectors of the UIGestureRecognizer.

However, if you are wanting to do this for unit tests, you could get access to the targets and selectors by doing the following:

```
NSArray *targets = [panGesture valueForKey:@"_targets"];
NSArray *actions = [panGesture valueForKey:@"_actions"];
```

You can then loop through those arrays and call the action on the target:

```
[target performSelector:selector withObject:panGesture];
```

Answer (score 2):

To "fake a pan gesture" I assume you mean move the view somewhere it currently isn't. `UIView` animations can be used for this.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Fake-A-Pan" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
self.frame = CGRectMake(/* new coordinates for frame here */);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

By using an animation to change the location of the view, you can essentially "fake a pan".
**Edit** As a comment suggested, Block-Based animations can also be used.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5f 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^ {
                     self.frame ... // adjust your view here 
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"Done animating");
                 }];
```

Comment: I use this for backward compatibility for deployment target 6.0 and Xcode 6.3.1. I use it like a "refresh", because I have a blank screen with UIScrollView and its background image.